# How to get values from JSON without knowing the numeric key names in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net

I have some JSON like this (truncated):

```
{
    "data": {
        "1001": {
            "id": 1001,
            "plaintext": "Slightly increases Movement Speed",
            "description": "<groupLimit>Limited to 1.</groupLimit><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Enhanced Movement:</unique> +25 Movement Speed<br><br><i>(Unique Passives with the same name don't stack.)</i>",
            "name": "Boots of Speed",
            "group": "BootsNormal"
        },
        "1004": {
            "id": 1004,
            "plaintext": "Slightly increases Mana Regen",
            "description": "<stats><mana>+25% Base Mana Regen </mana></stats>",
            "name": "Faerie Charm"
        },
        "1011": {
            "id": 1011,
            "plaintext": "Greatly increases Health",
            "description": "<stats>+380 Health</stats>",
            "name": "Giant's Belt"
        },
        "1018": {
            "id": 1018,
            "plaintext": "Moderately increases Critical Strike Chance",
            "description": "<stats>+15% Critical Strike Chance</stats>",
            "name": "Cloak of Agility"
        }
    }
}
```

[Full json here](http://pastebin.com/2PSQprhS)

If I try to get a name from only item one I would use `json("data")("3745")("name")` and the output would be: `name1`

I would like to skip all the numbers like this: `json("data")("*")("name")`.

Using the `*` wildcard does not work, so for the time being I'm using code like this:

```
For i = 1001 To 4000
    Try
        Dim jsonname As String = json(i.ToString)("name")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add(jsonname.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
Next
```

If it can get an item with the current `i` (lets say 3745) then it adds the name to the ComboBox and then advances to next `i` (3746).  If it can't get an item with the current value of `i` then it gives an exception and advances to next `i` (and on and on until 4000).

This actually works, but makes the application very slow (note that there's 50+ entries with each one a random id between 1001 and 4000, and I can't change the JSON).

Comment: First, that is not valid json, so it would be hard to be sure what to do with it.  In general, rather than parsing the json, you could deserialize it to a collection and use it as the CBo datasource.  The slowness likely results from adding to the UI control

Comment: it is valid because its from the League of Legends API

Comment: Visit http://jsonlint.com/.  You scrubbed it apparently and left out some punctuation starting with the enclosing `{...}`

Comment: i just copied a part, i know the thing is not correct without the full json and it is quite big so pls focus on what i ask and not on the json i have it working i can browse i can do it everything just not to ignore a part(the ids) 
json("data")("ignore this part")("name") so i dont have to use a for loop cicling trough desnesssary fields(why pass by id 3520 if it doenst exist for example)

Comment: There are **several** things wrong with it.  A fragment is fine, but it has to be valid if you want to get an answer which works!  Anyway, a DS would speed things up.  good luck

Comment: i just posted the whole part of the json working and validated on the link u sent, [here is the json](http://pastebin.com/2PSQprhS)

Comment: note that it is `"data"` in the good one?  That deserializes to a dictionary, so use a `BindingSource` using `Value` as the `DisplayMember`.  My system parses it, deserializes the inner dictionary and sets up the binding source in .25 secs.  Do be sure to override ToString in your class or since you seem to only want the names, leave out the other properties

Comment: could u give some code by chance? this part is quite new for me XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you seem to be stumbling over is the numeric keys for each of the items in the JSON.  Since you don't know what the keys are, except that they are somewhere between 1000 and 4000, you are trying each possible value in sequence, which ends up being pretty slow (especially since you are using a try/catch inside your loop to deal with the misses).

Fortunately you don't need to guess.  If you're using Json.Net (which I'm assuming you are; it's not clear from your question) then there's an easy way to iterate over values without knowing the key names.  Here is a short demo:

```
Dim json As String = _
"{" + _
    """data"": {" + _
        """1001"": {" + _
            """id"": 1001," + _
            """plaintext"": ""Slightly increases Movement Speed""," + _
            """description"": ""<groupLimit>Limited to 1.</groupLimit><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Enhanced Movement:</unique> +25 Movement Speed<br><br><i>(Unique Passives with the same name don't stack.)</i>""," + _
            """name"": ""Boots of Speed""," + _
            """group"": ""BootsNormal""" + _
        "}," + _
        """1004"": {" + _
            """id"": 1004," + _
            """plaintext"": ""Slightly increases Mana Regen""," + _
            """description"": ""<stats><mana>+25% Base Mana Regen </mana></stats>""," + _
            """name"": ""Faerie Charm""" + _
        "}," + _
        """1011"": {" + _
            """id"": 1011," + _
            """plaintext"": ""Greatly increases Health""," + _
            """description"": ""<stats>+380 Health</stats>""," + _
            """name"": ""Giant's Belt""" + _
        "}," + _
        """1018"": {" + _
            """id"": 1018," + _
            """plaintext"": ""Moderately increases Critical Strike Chance""," + _
            """description"": ""<stats>+15% Critical Strike Chance</stats>""," + _
            """name"": ""Cloak of Agility""" + _
        "}," + _
    "}" + _
"}"

Dim data As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)("data")

For Each item As JObject In data.Values
    Console.WriteLine("id: " & item("id").ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("name: " & item("name").ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("plaintext: " & item("plaintext").ToString())
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Output:

```
id: 1001
name: Boots of Speed
plaintext: Slightly increases Movement Speed

id: 1004
name: Faerie Charm
plaintext: Slightly increases Mana Regen

id: 1011
name: Giant's Belt
plaintext: Greatly increases Health

id: 1018
name: Cloak of Agility
plaintext: Moderately increases Critical Strike Chance
```

Comment: Thx for teh help that was what i needed :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If Not IsNothing(json(CStr(i))) then
    ComboBox4.Items.Add(json(CStr(i))("name"))
End if
```

Also remove the Try Catch, there is no need for it.

Comment: but still i have to use the for loop and i dont want it cause it makes performance insues u just change the try catch to that, that does the same thing exept the trow exception part